# Resample basemap in openlayers

Tags: openlayers, resampling

I have an application developed based on openlayers and I load a esri basemap ([https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Ocean/World_Ocean_Base/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}](https://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Ocean/World_Ocean_Base/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D))
From zoom level 11 and onwards, I received the attached image because there is no information to display.

I would like to know if there is any option to resample the previous level (in the esri JS api, there is the property "resampling")

Many thanks for your help.
Best regards.
Clara

Comment: You can specify a maxZoom on the source so the no data tiles do not appear and the view will overzoom tiles at the level you know is available https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-6t5cri?file=/main.js

Comment: Better still ESRI tile sources have a `blankTile` option https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/map-tile.htm.  If you set that to false in the URL the "no information to display" tiles are not returned, and as long as OpenLayers `useInterimTilesOnError` option is at the default setting and `preload` is enabled OpenLayers will handle the error by using tiles from the nearest available zoom level https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-ygiu8v?file=/main.js